# How to make a CommandBar persistent in WinRT?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I saw [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/276402/Adding-an-Application-Bar-to-your-XAML-Metro-appli) on the code project, where the author mentions the possibility of making an ApplicationBar persistent.

```
I want my app bar always visible!

You can make the app bars display at all times by setting the IsPersistent property to True.
```

I'd like to do the same in my Windows 8.1 (WinRT) project.  I can't see a IsPersistent property for the CommandBar class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx#properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CommandBar within the Page.Bottom[Top]AppBar areas will not give you this ability.  As presently defined, AppBars are transient and can always be dismissed by the user.  IsOpen/IsSticky are ways to help it stay open longer, but the user can always still dismiss them.

If you want a persistent 'appbar' feel that isn't dismissable, you'll want to just create something that stays bottom-aligned on your view.  You will however, be having different behavior than the user may expect given other apps.

Answer (score 2):

It's not IsPersistant, it's [IsSticky](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.issticky.aspx)

Comment: That's not the same thing.  If you set IsSticky to true the CommandBar is still not visible.  You can also set IsOpen to true as well to force it to be open, but the user can still right click on the page, and poof! it dissapears.

Comment: If you want a bar without any magic, then you can probably simply put it on your LayoutRoot, instead of in TopBar/BottomBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Closed Method of the CommandBar.

And set within the method IsOpen to True.

This way to force the CommandBar to always be visible even if the user press Windows+Z, Right click, etc.